# Apache Pivot, Coming out of Apache Incubator to Main, feedback?

Tags: java, ria, apache-pivot

[Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/index.html) is coming out of Apache Incubator in very near future.
In your opinion
What are pros and cons of it?
Any specific negative/positive points about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros: frakk yeah, this is how **Java** RIA should be architected like. Java & XML UI markup. Does anyone know why Sun has thrown away all its technologies (Java, Applets) to make a RIA? Why to invent a new language and throw away all the tools, frameworks of Java?! If I'm willing to learn a new language, I'm obviously going to go for Flash and not FX.

Cons: Multimedia support remains horrible. IMHO no chance of impact until users have to click on a huge, ugly and horrible security warning if the program just wants to access the mic & sound.